# Filling `std::optional<T>` via API taking output `T*` parameter

Tags: c++, option-type, c++17

I have a legacy non-blocking dequeue API that looks like this:

```
template <typename T>
bool bad_queue<T>::try_dequeue(T* out);
    // Returns 'false' if there was nothing to dequeue.
    // Returns 'true' and sets '*out' to the dequeued item otherwise.
```

I would like to wrap `bad_queue<T>` into my own `cool_queue<T>` which returns an `std::optional<T>` from its `try_dequeue` member function:

```
template <typename T>
class cool_queue
{
private:
    bad_queue<T> _q;

public:
    std::optional<T> try_dequeue();
};
```

This is the way I currently implement `try_dequeue`:

```
template <typename T>
std::optional<T> cool_queue<T>::try_dequeue()
{
    T temp;
    const auto ok = _q.try_dequeue(&temp);
    if(!ok) { return std::nullopt; }
    return {std::move(temp)};
}
```

**Is there any way of avoiding the temporary `temp` buffer and directly construct the value returned by `_q.try_dequeue` inside the optional?** Example:

```
// PSEUDOCODE
template <typename T>
std::optional<T> cool_queue<T>::try_dequeue()
{
    std::optional<T> temp;
    const auto ok = _q.try_dequeue(&temp.storage());
    if(!ok) { return std::nullopt; }

    temp.assume_has_object();
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Can't use `if (init; condition)...else...` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't really *construct* the value in optional via pointer, but your legacy api does not allow that anyway. You can instead default-construct a value in optional and pass a pointer to that:

```
template <typename T>
std::optional<T> cool_queue<T>::try_dequeue()
{
    std::optional<T> temp;
    const auto ok = _q.try_dequeue(&temp.emplace());
    if (!ok) { temp.reset(); }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this compiles, since `emplace()` is a template class member and `try_dequeue()` takes a `T *` as a parameter.

Comment: Better still, you could declare `temp` as -> `std::optional<T> temp(std::in_place);`

Comment: @SamVarshavchik why would that be a problem? `.emplace()` returns `T&`

Comment: How does `T *` get type-converted to `&std::optional::emplace`, which is a pointer to a template class member? Even the question makes it clear. `try_dequeue` takes a `T *` as a parameter. Not a pointer to some template class member.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Um, `&temp.emplace()` is `&(temp.emplace())` not `(&temp.emplace)()`.

Comment: Ok, so this is still default-constructing `T`, in all cases, and then destroying it if `dequeue()` fails.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik you need a default-constructed `T` anyway, `try_dequeue` does not appear to construct the object in the storage it's argument points to, only assign to an object already constructed there.

Comment: It's silly to default-initialize the `optional` and then immediately call `emplace`. Just value-initialize the stored object in place: `std::optional<T> temp{std::in_place}; const auto ok = _q.try_dequeue(&*temp);`

Answer (score 1):

From your description, it would appear that the legacy `try_dequeue` function does not have any responsibility of initializing the memory allocated for the target object  (*"... sets '`*out`' to the ..."*), so the target object will need to have been constructed prior to the the legacy (possibly object-assigning) invocation. Specifically, for the target object being the value wrapped by an `std::optional` instance, the instance must contain a (wrapped) value if we are to access its address.

The requirements to the observers of `std::optional` ([[optional.observe]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/optional.observe)) implicitly specify UB if `*someOptional` does not contain a value; and from [[optional.optional]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/optional.optional):

> Any instance of `optional<T>` at any given time either contains a
>   value or does not contain a value. When an instance of optional
>   contains a value, it means that an object of type T, referred to as
>   the optional object's contained value, is allocated within the storage
>   of the optional object.

The only way you'd circumvent this is to change the legacy API.

As [mentioned in a comment by @Casey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46974736/filling-stdoptionalt-via-api-taking-output-t-parameter#comment80900930_46974873), you could value-initialize the target object in place, and refactor the `cool_queue<T>::try_dequeue()` accordingly, e.g.:

```
template <typename T>
std::optional<T> cool_queue<T>::try_dequeue()
{  
    std::optional<T> temp{std::in_place};
    return _q.try_dequeue(&*temp) ? temp : std::nullopt;
}
```